# Running Web Apps locally

Tags: php, mysql, node.js

I've been contracted for building a Journal Service (Web, Android and iOS) that requires the development of an offline version for use in Windows and if possible Ubuntu too. The end user's web interface and the mobile apps are currently running with data from an API endpoint hosted on an API Gateway + Lambda (Node) + RDS Stack. For the offline desktop application, I would like to use the same browser client code and run a local server to act as the API endpoint. This requires that I have a system in place to run a MySQL server locally and have a syncing system in place to sync the updates to the local server.

What solution would be recommended for this purpose of replicating MySQL DBs. Ideally something free. Since I'm the design phase of reworking the project, I am currently open to any kind of suggestions, including shifting from MySQL. The data is entirely textual content and is around 8GB now. It will slowly expand to about 30GB over the next 2 years.

Comment: You're in for a lot of hurt. Although lambda runs node.js and you use api gateway to call it it is still a different development process. You are going to end up with two different code bases.

Comment: AWS RDS has a pick from 6 different database engines so you would have to do some rewriting if the local database is not the same as the one in AWS RDS.

Comment: Yes, the 2 code bases is an issue, but compared to complexity of build a new UI with all the bells and whistles mandated by the client, porting the API logic is economical.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but not easy. I have done variants of this a few times, including 2 with mixture of Linux & Windows systems. A few key steps:

1 - Put all the system configuration parameters - directory paths, MySQL credentials, time zone, API keys, etc. - in a single file. Reference that file in the top (e.g., `require_once('serverinfo.php');` of each PHP file. If you do it right, you will end up with code that is, except for that one file, **identical** for multiple Linux & Windows systems, provided you use similar (e.g., 5.x) PHP versions across all installations.

2 - Transfer is a pain, no doubt about it. The catch is that you most likely can't use any official "replication" because of the different (and not constantly connected) systems. I have used two different methods, and the right answer depends on the customer's requirements. Both work best if the transfer is primarily unidirectional.

a) Add an update timestamp and a transfer flag (multiple if there are more than 2 servers). Any time a record is added or updated, set the timestamp to now() and transfer=1. To transfer data, select where transfer=1 and either put everything into a text file (CSV, JSON or whatever format you prefer) and transmit that to the other system (FTP, Email, etc.) *or* if you can have temporary connection between the system you can use a https interface between the two servers to transfer the data "live". On receive, the 2nd server checks the timestamp to make sure the data is newer than what you already have and update the database. If the transfer is a live https interface, send a message back to the 1st server to tell it to clear the transfer flag. If the transfer is a file-based batch mode then the transfer flag needs to be reset when the file is sent (and hope it gets through to the other side).

b) Dump everything every time you want to transfer. This can be **mysqldump** or an equivalent you write yourself. This is by far simpler than the first method, but doesn't generally work well once the data gets to a certain size - and you may already be at that point with 8 GB of data.

Comment: Although this is good advice. I don't know why the OP put PHP as a tag since it's not written in PHP.

Comment: @Darkrum Well, I based my reply on the key code being in PHP based on the tag. GIGO

Comment: I'm sorry about the PHP tag. This piece of software has seen a lot of revisions over the past decade most of which used PHP as a code base. Initial idea was to bundle php and Apache too. But we decided not to do that considering the further increase in complexity.

Comment: The MySQL dump is an option which we considered. But size issues is a concern. The http option is what we have in mind right now.

Comment: Can someone point me in the right direction to a MySQL replication solution. paid or otherwise. Data will be unidirectional.

Comment: @AthulRaj I've never done true MySQL replication beyond a very controlled environment (e.g., AWS RDS). I'm not sure how you would do that with 2 different systems without a close-to-always-up connection. Unidirectional makes me think an application-level https: based transfer would work well, but I've always built my own code for that and I've never turned it into a commercial package - but maybe someone else has.